# function protectAdmin not working

Tags: php, mysql, session

Hi i have a problem with my function protectAdmin which should deny access to users that are not admins and not logged in however when i call the function on a specific page it wont let me see that page even though i am logged in as admin.When put the same code from the function without enclosing it into a function it works well.Here is my code:

header.php:

```
session_start();
$userid=$_SESSION['userid'];
$username=$_SESSION['username'];
```

functions.php:

```
function adminProtect(){
  if($username && $userid){
    require "connect.php";
    $query=mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT*FROM user WHERE username='$username'");
    $row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($query);
    $type=$row['type'];
    if($type!=1){
        header("Location:index.php");
    }   
  }else{
    header("Location:index.php");
  }
}
```

adminpage.php:

```
include "header.php";
include "functions.php";
protectAdmin();
```

In my table type 1 is admin and type 0 is user.Any suggestions?

Comment: function scope issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you are calling the wrong function and second you need to give the variables to your function as parameters and make your function accept variables.

functions.php:

```
function adminProtect($username,$userid){

  if($username && $userid){
    require "connect.php";
    $query=mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT*FROM user WHERE username='$username'");
    $row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($query);
    $type=$row['type'];
    if($type!=1){
      header("Location:index.php");
    }    
  }else{
    header("Location:index.php");
  }
}
```

adminpage.php:

```
include "header.php";
include "functions.php";
adminProtect($username,$userid);
```

Comment: i combined the two answers i got and now it is working.Thank you guys for the quick help you are the best

Answer (score 2):

this

```
function adminProtect($username,$userid){
```

and this

```
 protectAdmin($username,$userid);
```